# Volley Json Parse

Tags: java, android, json

hizmetlerimiz: {
yazilim: [
"Web Tasarım",
"E-Ticaret",
"Logo Tasarım & Kurumsal Kimlik",
"Web Hosting & Domain",
"Masaüstü ve Mobil Uygulamalar"
],
network: [
"Network Satış & Teknik Servis",
"Server Satış & Teknik Servis",
"Bilgisayar & OEM Parça Satış",
"BT Danışmanlık",
"Web Sitesi Çeviri Hizmeti"
],
elektronik: [
"E-Fatura & E-Arşiv",
"E-Defter",
"E-İmza",
"Kayıtlı Elektronik Posta (KEP)",
"E-İrsaliye & E-Bilet"
]
}

Comment: Can you kindly ask question?

Comment: public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { try { JSONArray arrYazilar= response.getJSONArray("hizmetlerimiz"); for (int i = 0; i < arrYazilar.length(); i++){ JSONObject yazi = arrYazilar.getJSONObject(i);*emphasized text* String baslik = yazi.getString("yazilim"); Log.d("YAZI BAŞLIK:",baslik); yaziBasliklari.add(baslik); } } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54795798/edit) your question with code and error messages.

Comment: I can't get an Error Message. Json stems from its structure. The Json object has the Json array in it. How can I fix this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

"hizmetlerimiz" is not a json array, it is json object, so you should get it like this;

```
response.getJSONObject("hizmetlerimiz")
```

"hizmetlerimiz" contains arrays like "yazilim", you can reach it;

```
response.getJSONObject("hizmetlerimiz").getJSONArray("yazilim")
```

Comment: teşekkürler. Ama tam olarak kodu o döngü kısmısını atabilirmisiniz rica etsem.

Comment: public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONObject yazilar = response.getJSONObject("hizmetlerimiz");
            JSONArray arrYazilim = yazilar.getJSONArray("yazilim");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrYazilim.length(); i++)
            {
                String yazi = "yazilim";
                String baslik = arrYazilim.get(i).toString();
                Log.d("YAZI BAŞLIK:",baslik);
                yaziBasliklari.add(baslik);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: Sorun çözüldü. Tekrardan teşekkür ederim :)